# web2py and d3.js compatibility

Tags: python, d3.js, web2py

I'm a relatively unexperienced developer starting on a new project to expose some pre-existing Python analytical libraries' functions in a web application through javascript visualization library d3.js. I've explored the web2py framework for Python, and would just like to ask a simple question:

Are there any compatibility issues I should be aware of between web2py and d3.js?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there should not be any compatibility issues. web2py is primarily a server-side framework, and D3 is all client-side. They are completely independent. web2py does provide some client-side scaffolding, but it is optional and won't interfere with D3 anyway.